# Mostrar registro sem atualizar página

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, socket.io

Boa tarde, **eu juro que já pesquisei em tudo que é lugar, mas só vejo ensinando a criar chat :'(**

Eu estou desenvolvendo um projeto(estilo TV corporativa) para a empresa que trabalho, e o projeto estava servindo muito bem até que a sede gostou deste projeto pediu para implementar em todas outras unidades(inclusive a sede) e pediu algumas coisas "a mais" e é nessas coisas "a mais" que me veio esse problema de atualizar automaticamente.

**1.** *Não sou profissional, sei apenas o básico e me viro com o que sei*;
 **2.** *Como aprendi tudo na internet o projeto talvez não esteja na forma padrão ou atual*;
 **3.** *Aprendi tudo na internet*;

O projeto funciona assim:

1. RH insere os informativos.
2. É exibido no index(de acordo com a unidade). Exemplo: localhost/sicc/geral/rj/bangu (projeto/controller/função/parametro)
3. Dentro da view(que eu chamei de slide) mostra todas as imagens para aquela unidade, todas para a região(a função) as imagens e todas as imagens que serve para todas regiões e unidades

Pesquisei sobre diversas ferramentas que aparentemente resolve o meu problema, mas como disse no inicio "só vejo ensinando a criar chat", por isso vim até o SOpt para ver se consigo alguma luz ou caminho para a resolução do meu problema.

Projeto:

Controller:

```
public function rj($unidade = null)
{               
    if (!isset($unidade)) {
        redirect('aplicacao');
    } else {
        if (($unidade === "Caxias") || ($unidade === "caxias")) {
            $unidade = "Caxias";
            $this->load->view('layouts/inicio_slide');
            $this->load->model('slide_model', 'slide');
            $dados['todasR'] = $this->slide->todas_unidade($unidade);
            $dados['fotos'] = $this->slide->todas_fotos_publicas($unidade);
            $this->load->view('slide', $dados);
            $this->load->view('layouts/fim_slide');
        } elseif (($unidade === "Bangu") || ($unidade === "bangu")) {
            $unidade = "Bangu";
            $this->load->view('layouts/inicio_slide');
            $this->load->model('slide_model', 'slide');
            $dados['todasR'] = $this->slide->todas_unidade($unidade);
            $dados['fotos'] = $this->slide->todas_fotos_publicas($unidade);
            $this->load->view('slide', $dados);
            $this->load->view('layouts/fim_slide');
        } elseif (($unidade === "grio") || ($unidade === "GRIO")) {
            $unidade = "Grande Rio";
            $this->load->view('layouts/inicio_slide');
            $this->load->model('slide_model', 'slide');
            $dados['todasR'] = $this->slide->todas_unidade($unidade);
            $dados['fotos'] = $this->slide->todas_fotos_publicas($unidade);
            $this->load->view('slide', $dados);
            $this->load->view('layouts/fim_slide');
        } else {
            redirect('aplicacao');
        }
    }       
}
```

View:

```
<?php if((count($fotos) === 0) && (count($todasR) === 0)): ?>
    <div id="slides">
        <div class="slides-container foto-slide">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/wallpaper.jpg') ?>" class="foto-slide" >
        </div>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div id="slides">
        <div class="slides-container foto-slide">
            <?php foreach($fotos as $foto): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/fotos/'.$foto['foto']) ?>" class="foto-slide" >
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php if(isset($todasR)): ?>
                <?php foreach($todasR as $todaR): ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/fotos/'.$todaR['foto']) ?>" class="foto-slide" >
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Model:

```
public function busca_regional($id_regional)
    {
        $resultado = $this->db->select('*')
        ->where('id_regional', $id_regional)
        ->get('regionais');
        return $resultado->result();            
    }  
    public function busca_unidade($unidadeL)
    {
        $resultado = $this->db->select('*')
        ->where('unidade', $unidadeL)
        ->get('unidades');
        return $resultado->result();

    }
    public function busca_unidade_todas($id_regional)
    {
        $resultado = $this->db->select('*')
        ->where('id_regional', $id_regional)
        ->where('unidade', 'Todas')
        ->get('unidades');
        return $resultado->result();

    }
    public function todas_unidade($unidadeL)
    {
        $unidade = $this->busca_unidade($unidadeL);
        foreach ($unidade as $uni) {
            $id_regional_local = $uni->id_regional;
        }            
        $regional = $this->busca_regional($id_regional_local);
        foreach ($regional as $reg) {
            $id_regional = $reg->id_regional;
        }
        $toda = $this->busca_unidade_todas($id_regional);
        foreach ($toda as $tod) {
            $id_unidade = $tod->id_unidade;
        }

        $resultado = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('fotos')
        ->where('id_regional', $id_regional)
        ->where('id_unidade', $id_unidade)
        ->where('publica', true)
        ->get();

        return $resultado->result_array();

    }
    public function todas_fotos_publicas($unidadeL)
    {
        $unidade = $this->busca_unidade($unidadeL);
        foreach ($unidade as $uni) {
            $id_unidade = $uni->id_unidade;
        }

        $resultado = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('fotos')
        ->where('publica', true)
        ->where('id_unidade', $id_unidade)
        ->get();
        return $resultado->result_array();
    }
```

Me desculpe, se por acaso ficou confuso.

Comment: Qual é o resultado esperado?

Comment: Assim que a pessoa incluir o informativo no site mostrar automaticamente no index

Answer (score 0):

Não se se vai servir para você, mas aqui na empresa também utilizamos Painéis em TV que exibem informações que são capturadas diretamente do Banco de Dados em tempo real, e para conseguir realizar esse tipo de atualização utilizei o seguinte:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Ajax() {
    var $http, $self = arguments.callee;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      $http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      try {
        $http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
      } catch(e) {
        $http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
      }
    }

    if ($http) {
      $http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (/4|^complete$/.test($http.readyState)) {
          document.getElementById('SuaDivQueIraAtualizar').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
          setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 3000);
        }
      };
      $http.open('GET', 'index.php' + '?' + new Date().getTime(), true);
      $http.send(null);
    }
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function() {Ajax();}, 3000);</script>
```

**Obs:** Esse script fica no **HEAD**

Basta você altrar o texto **SuaDivQueIraAtualizar** para a TAG que você deseja atualizar no painel, um exemplo disso seria, logo abaixo do `<body>` você adicionar uma `<div id="Geral">` nomeando ela da forma como desejar, no meu caso coloquei **Geral** então dessa forma basta mudar o nome **SuaDivQueIraAtualizar** para **Geral**

Comment: Implementei esse código no meu projeto e percebi que quando da os 3 segundos ele atualiza a <div> , mas o que tem dentro da <div> simplesmente some.
Eu fui tentar entender esse código e percebi que  `$http.open('GET', 'index.php' + '?' + new Date().getTime(), true);`  quando comentado ele não causa esse erro, porém ele não atualiza a <div>

Comment: Eu fiz esse teste aqui 'if ($http.readyState === 4 && $http.status === 200) { document.getElementById('geral').innerHTML = $http.responseText; setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 3000); } else{ alert($http.readyState); alert($http.status); alert('ta foda'); }' O '$http.readyState' me retorna com valor 2(HEADERS_RECEIVED), e dps me retorna o valor 4(DONE) e o $http.status me retorna com valor 200(ok)